# ValueError: need at least one array to concatenate on the line matrix_A = np.vstack(vectors)

Tags: error-handling

i am new to python and this code shows error need at least one array to concatenate
i have reviewed other similar problems but still not quite sure what to do

```
import numpy as np
import os
from skimage import io, color
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA


grayscale_images = []
for img in cv_img:
    gray_img = color.rgb2gray(img)
    grayscale_images.append(gray_img)

vectors = []
for img in grayscale_images:
    vector = img.flatten()
    vectors.append(vector)

matrix_A = np.vstack(vectors)
pca = PCA(n_components=10)  
pca.fit(matrix_A)


mean_vector = pca.mean_
components = pca.components_
reconstructed_images = []
for vector in vectors:
    reconstructed_vector = mean_vector + np.dot(components.T, vector - mean_vector)
    reconstructed_image = reconstructed_vector.reshape(img.shape)
    reconstructed_images.append(reconstructed_image)


for i, img in enumerate(reconstructed_images):
    io.imshow(img)
    io.show()
```